# Сгруппировать элементы массива

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов

```
[
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 23}
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 21}
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 40}
  {type: 'hsc', currentDept: 83}
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 10}
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 51}
]
```

Как можно сделать из этих исходных данных массив объектов такого вида?

```
[
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 84}
  {type: 'hsc', currentDept: 83}
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 61}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функциональным подходом, и без побочных эффектов (типа изменения элементов исходного массива):

```js
const arr = [
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 23}, 
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 21}, 
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 40}, 
  {type: 'hsc', currentDept: 83}, 
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 10}, 
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 51}, 
]; 

let grouped = Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((r, { type, currentDept:cd }) => ((r[type] = (r[type] || 0) + cd), r), {})
).map(([ type, currentDept ]) => ({ type, currentDept })); 

console.log(grouped);
```

ES8+

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```js
let d = [
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 23},
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 21},
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 40},
  {type: 'hsc', currentDept: 83},
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 10},
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 51}
];

function collapse(d) {
  d = d.reduce((a, e) => (a[e.type] = (a[e.type]||0) + e.currentDept, a), {});
  return Object.keys(d).map(key => ({type: key, currentDept: d[key]}))
}

console.log(collapse(d))
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = [
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 23},
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 21},
  {type: 'credit', currentDept: 40},
  {type: 'hsc', currentDept: 83},
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 10},
  {type: 'alimony', currentDept: 51}
];

function group(arr) {
  var r1 = arr.reduce((r, el) => {
    if (typeof r[el.type] == "undefined") {
      r[el.type] = 0;
    }
    r[el.type] += el.currentDept;
    return r;
  }, {});
  var r2 = [];
  for (var key in r1)
    r2.push({ type: key, currentDept: r1[key] });
  return r2;
}

console.log(group(input));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)